# Mongoose - How to select a specific object inside an array of a populated field in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have populated a virtual in Mongoose, the populated virtual will retrieve an array of objects.

```
 objects:{[name:'xxx',age:20],[name:'yyy',age:21],[name:'zzz', age:23]}
```

How do I make it that it only retrieves one element I specify?

```
...
.populate({
   path:'someVirtual',
   select:'objects', //get only the 'objects' array
   options: {where:'objects',elemMatch:{name:'zzz'}} //this is what I tried 
                                                     //but it doesn't work
  )}
 .exec(function(err,docs){
    //handle
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `match` inside populate

```
.populate({
   path:'someVirtual',
   match: { objects: { $elemMatch: { name: 'zzz' } } },
   select: 'objects'                                        
})
```

and if you want to use projection then

```
.populate({
   path:'someVirtual',
   match: { objects: { $elemMatch: { name: 'zzz' } } },
   select: { objects: { $elemMatch: { name: 'zzz' } } }                                   
})
```

Comment: It worked, thank you! This helped a lot, I tried reading the docs but I felt like the usage examples weren't clear. I hope they'd make it more detailed in the future.